# Why do angular cli commands only work if preceded by npm run?

Tags: angular-cli

I upgraded from Angular 13 to 14 built, served and ran successfully.
I then upgraded fabricjs to the latest version; built, served and ran successfully.
I do not remember doing anything else before I attempted to run ng upgrade to move to 15. That was when I first received the error "The system cannot find the path specified."

I can run cli commands but only preceded by "npm run"
[image]

I have the %APPDATA% path to ng.js in my path environment variable.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the cli globally.
I have deleted and reinstall node_modules several times.

All of the cli commands appear to work if they are preceded by "npm run"

Clearly there is something wrong in my setup. I just can't figure anywhere else to look for the problem